# MobaXterm URL Protocol Handler Usage

Tags: html, ssh, url-scheme, protocol-handler, custom-url-protocol

I am wanting to deploy a series of MobaXterm connections (SSH connections) to our users and would like to look at creating a webpage where the users can simply invoke a chosen session by clicking on a link.

I can see that MobaXterm supports this by installing (installed by default) the URL Protocol Handler but I do not know and cannot find anywhere any syntax for the HTML links to invoke the named sessions.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction to look please?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this :

```
<a href="MobaXterm:ssh localhost">ssh localhost</a>
```

allowed me to open a session, but il also created a new 'saved session' and saturated my quota so I am not sure it is the real solution.
But a least it looks like 'mobaxterm' is the protocol, if it can help anybody ending up here. This feature sure lacks documentation :)

Comment: This worked for me too.  I was also able to specify the user like:
<a href='MobaXterm:ssh "user@hostname"'>ssh hostname</a>

I agree it does fill up the "free" version's session list though.

Answer (score 0):

I e-mailed Mobatek with the same question. It turns out if you right-click the "User Sessions" node and pick "[Generate HTML web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t81oc.png)", it will make a web page containing `mobaxterm:` protocol links to all your existing sessions. It looks like it's designed for exactly your use case, making a webpage to share with other users, so you may be able to just use that generated page as-is.

If you do want to generate your own links, it's a little trickier. I haven't really tried to understand the encoding yet; it's definitely not designed to be particularly user-readable, but since you can make any session you want and export it to a link it shouldn't be too hard to reverse-engineer the fields you care about.